# Failure to display icons and text in the software

Tags: display, icons, text

whatever I do, when installing and working with the software, the icons and text are not displayed according to the attached file, and I use Visual Box.
[Failure to display icons and text in the software](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tsT2.png)

Comment: This looks like a debian question, to be posted on appropriate SE site.